# 'Show more' button shows nothing more

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, profile-page, mobile-web

I was just reading [this](http://www.stackoverflow.com/users/2877241/vlad-from-moscow) user's about me. I saw a `show more` button

[image]

When I clicked it,nothing more was shown. Only the `show more` button disappeared

[image]

I think this is a minor bug and needs to be removed

P.S: I don't know if this happens on any PC, I was using OperaMini on my phone.

Comment: What mobile browser are you using? I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: @MartijinPieters ,Opera Mini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Opera mini, which is **not supported**.

See [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) and [Unable to start a bounty using Opera Mini](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177352/unable-to-start-a-bounty-using-opera-mini/177509#177509).

The issue is just not present in mobile browsers that *are* supported, nor in supported desktop browsers.